# How can I perform multiple linear models by accumulating the groups in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a database with stable isotope measurements: deuterium and oxygen_18.

```
Year    Deuterium   Oxygen_18
2005    -28 -4.6
2005    -27 -4
2005    -47 -6.1
2005    -28 -3.8
2005    -54 -7.2
2005    -27 -5
2005    -59 -8.8
2005    -39 -5.9
2005    -32 -5.3
2005    -15 -3.2
2005    -19 -3.4
2005    -35 -5.1
2006    -51 -7.7
2006    -30 -5
2006    -33 -5.4
2006    -40 -6.4
2006    -38 -6.4
2006    -62 -8.9
2006    -47 -7.3
2006    -30 -4.7
2006    -22 -4
2006    -19 -3.3
2007    -19 -3.3
2007    -31 -5.3
2007    -59 -8.6
2007    -74 -10.6
2007    -19 -3.1
2007    -30 -5.6
2007    -6  -2.1
2007    13  -0.9
2007    -15.6   -2.6
2008    -47.8   -6.9
2008    -33.8   -6.4
2008    -38.8   -7
2008    -29.7   -6.2
2008    3.4 -2.3
2008    -5.6    -2.2
2008    -1.2    -1
2008    18.8    3.2
2008    -0.4    -1.6
2008    16  0.5
2009    -13.7   -2.8
2009    -28.7   -5.2
2009    -40.6   -6.5
2009    -28.3   -5.6
2009    -71.7   -10.1
2009    -57.6   -9
2009    -67 -9.8
2010    -38.7   -7.4
2010    -37.6   -6.7
2010    -8.7    -3.6
2010    -54.1   -8.4
2010    -57.7   -8.9
2010    -54.8   -8.8
2010    -15 -4.2
2010    -15.5   -4.1
2010    -14.2   -4.2
2010    -25.1   -4.7
2011    -46.3   -7.4
2011    -29.4   -5.2
2011    -43.6   -7.5
2011    -32 -6.1
2011    -25.6   -4.9
2011    -35.6   -6.6
2011    -54.7   -8.7
2011    -30.9   -6.4
2011    14.5    -1.4
2011    -5.5    -3
2011    2.4 -2.3
2011    4.9 -1.7
2012    -8.3    -2.7
2012    -64 -9.6
2012    -54.2   -7.8
2012    -17.2   -4.5
2012    -22.6   -4.3
2012    -23.3   -4.9
2012    -3.9    -3.3
2012    2.2 -2.9
2012    4   -2.1
2012    -25.5   -5.2
2012    -34.8   -6.1
2013    -19.1   -4.2
2013    -25.5   -5.4
2013    -42.5   -7.6
2013    -27.8   -5.9
2013    -68.7   -10.3
2013    -10.8   -3.7
2013    -22.8   -5.1
2013    -25.1   -5.5
2013    -30.1   -6.1
2013    -2.9    -2.4
2013    -20.3   -4
2014    -27.4   -4.9
2014    -28.4   -5.4
2014    -35.7   -5.9
2014    -50.3   -7.7
2014    -64.7   -11
2014    -30.5   -6.3
2014    -30.5   -5.8
2014    -9.1    -3.4
2014    -25 -5.9
2014    4.7 -2.4
2014    -14.3   -4.2
2014    -5.3    -0.7
```

Both variables have been quantified monthly (there are some NAs per month) in rainwater from 2005 to 2014. In this case, the year is a group or a factor.
I am trying to perform a lineal regression lm(deuterium ~ oxygen_18) by group (by year) but in such a way that the first model run the first group (2005), the second model analyzes the first and the second group (2005 and 2006), the third model run the first, the second and third groups (2005, 2006 and 2007) and so on until the latest model includes all the data from 2005 to 2014.

So far I have been able to perform the regression by group:

```
library(tidyverse)

model.year <- df %>%
  nest(data = -Year) %>% 
  mutate(
    fit = map(
      data,
      ~ lm(Deuterium ~ Oxygen_18, data = .x)
      ),
    tidied = map(fit, tidy)
  ) %>% 
  unnest(tidied)
```

Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

There may be some magic tidyverse "rolling/expanding frame" way to do this, but a `for` loop works fine ...

### load packages

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
```

### set up baseline model, results list

I fit the model to the full data first so I can be lazy and use `update()`.  This is a little wasteful since I'm fitting to the full data again in the last step of the `for` loop ...

```r
m0 <- lm(Deuterium ~ Oxygen_18, data = dd)
dd$Year <- factor(dd$Year)
Ly <- levels(dd$Year)
ny <- length(Ly)
res <- vector("list", ny)
names(res) <- sprintf("%s-%s", Ly[1], Ly)
```

### fit models and tidy

```r
for (i in 1:ny) {
   res[[i]] <- update(m0, data = dplyr::filter(dd, Year %in% Ly[1:i]))
}
map_dfr(res, broom::tidy, .id = "years")
```